# Тип придаточного предложения

Tags: синтаксис

> Ты уж не злись, **что я тебя так давно не навещал**.

Скажите, пожалуиста, как правильно задать вопрос: не злись *на что?* или не злись *потому что один человек не навещал другого*? 
Одним словом мне хочется знать, это дополнительное придаточное или придаточное причины. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ты уж не злись (на то), что я тебя так давно не навещал.

Это **придаточное изъяснительное** (не придаточное причины), опорное слово со значением эмоциональной реакции.

**Другие примеры**: Все возмущались, что спектакль отменили. Все радовались, что щенок нашелся.

Comment: все поняла! спасибо за экстра примеры, полезно!